# Swing mouseListener not triggering event in Linux KDE

Tags: java, linux, swing

My problem is that mouseListener not throwing an event for the TrayIcon when i click the icon in the tray and the same code works perfectly in Windows.
I am setting Imageicon that changes images frequently with no Problem.So i hope its not completely numb enough or frozen in its state.

Cant understand if problem is with KDE Graphics or Swing with Linux problem.
For reproducing I am using linux KDE
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS,
Release:        16.04,
Codename:       xenial,
Java 1.8

What i have done is so far is -> 
Used SystemTray and therefore created Popupmenu,Dimension for setting screen size
These are the two breakpoints which i am expecting to get an event from my Eclipse Debugger.
Btw the SystemTray.isSupported() function works fine.

```
this.trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, applicationName, this.popup);

this.trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                setVisible(true);
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                setVisible(true);

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                setVisible(true);

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                setVisible(true);

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        this.trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                setVisible(true);
                setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);

                MainWindow.this.trayIcon.displayMessage("Action Event",
                    "An Action Event Has Been Performed!",
                    TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);

            }
        });
this.tray.add(this.trayIcon);
```

Anybody has any Suggestions on how i can catch the mouse click event on the TrayIcon of my Software and maximize the window after i minimized it in the tray?

Comment: *"Forgive me when the question is not well formatted or is completely understandable."* Yeh OK I forgive you, but speaking of questions, you seem to have forgotten to ask one, or at least to have added a `?` to the end of it. Please [edit] to correct that oversight.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: the current "answer" seems even worse. Am I missing something or does it also seem to you to provide nothing of use?

Comment: *"Anybody has any Suggestions?"* 1) Ask a more specific question e.g. *"How to make mouse listener work with tray icon?"* 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). @HovercraftFullOfEels you're right, but it's now gone. Nice call on challenging it.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Thanks for your efforts

Comment: Does it work on other platforms or is OS specific?

Comment: Yes it works on Windows! I am not 100% sure if its OS specific but i assume so because the breakpoints doesn't trigger mouse event when i click on the TrayIcon

Comment: Any reason on -1 ?